# Bigquery: Query repeated key-value to into single row

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a schema like below where I have repeated field with key-value object:

```
metadata.date               STRING  NULLABLE    
metadata.properties         RECORD  REPEATED    
metadata.properties.key     STRING  NULLABLE    
metadata.properties.value   STRING  NULLABLE
```

I have row like
{date: "01-02", properties: [{key: "foo", value: "bar"}, {key: "bar", value: "baz"},...]

I want to query everything in repeated field as columns of a single row. Note we have 100+ entries in `properties` repeated field. Is there a way to achieve this without 100+ subqueries?
My current query is:

```
SELECT
    date,
    (SELECT value FROM unnest(metadata.properties) WHERE key='foo') as foo,
    (SELECT value FROM unnest(metadata.properties) WHERE key='bar') as bar,
    ...
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below - dynamically extracts all keys and builds needed query executed by `execute immediate`

```
execute immediate (select '''select * except(row_id)
from (
  select to_json_string(t) row_id, metadata.date, key, value
  from `project.dataset.table` t, unnest(metadata.properties) property
)
pivot (max(value) for key in (''' || string_agg(distinct '"' || key || '"' order by '"' || key || '"') || '''))'''
from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(metadata.properties)
)
```

Note: Most likely you can exclude/remove use of `to_json_string(t) row_id` and respectively `except(row_id)`, but I included it here because I don't know all details of the rest of your scheam and I wanted to make sure rows are preserved as is and not accidentally grouped